# 4 simple toggle switches! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css

I got this code from a youtube video but, it doesn't work. So, I put it into jsfiddle and fixed everything it said was wrong but, EEERRRRRR.... it still doesn't work. There should be four sliding on/off switches. Yet I only have this one giant blob that doesn't do anything but, sit there and laugh at me. Any help out there?

http://jsfiddle.net/p2bxkyv8/

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Toggle Switch</title>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
     <h1>Toggle Switch</h1>
     <lable class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span class="slider"></span>
     </lable>

     <lable class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" checked>
     <span class="slider"></span>
     </lable>

     <lable class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span class="slider"></span>
     </lable>

     <lable class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" checked>
     <span class="slider"></span>
     </lable>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

  .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    }

  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    }

  .switch {
    position: relitive;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    }

  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 34px;
    }

  .switch input { display: none; }

  .slider::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 50px;
    }

  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #ff278c;
    }

  input:checked + .slider::before {
    transform: translateX(50px);
    }
```

Comment: `lable` should be `label` and `position: relitive` on the `.switch` styles should be `position: relative`. Voting to close as 'a simple typographical error'.

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel like an idiot now. I must need some sleep or something. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

you have a typo, `position: relitive;` is wrong:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  }
```

and `lable` should be `label`

Comment: I didn't down vote anyone. just got back. Thanks guys. I feel like an idiot now. I must need some sleep or something. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but questions which are predicated on a typo (or two) should not be answered; we have a specific close reason for that, since it is unlikely that someone else will have the exact same misspelling.

Comment: Just for the record. I can't vote anyone down. I don't have the rep.

Answer (score -1):

This works. Fix `lable` to `label` and `relitive` to `relative`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  }

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  }

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
  }

.switch input { display: none; }

.slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 50px;
  }

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #ff278c;
  }

input:checked + .slider::before {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Toggle Switch</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Toggle Switch</h1>
 <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider"></span>
 </label>

 <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
   <span class="slider"></span>
 </label>

 <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider"></span>
 </label>

 <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
   <span class="slider"></span>
 </label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```